# Can this statement be considered a threat?

Tags: united-states, florida

If you write in an email, "Enter at your own risk. Anyone trying to enter a home without permission or consent will be treated as a trespasser or intruder.". Is that considered at threat?

For country specific or local laws, United States / Florida.

Comment: Why is that a threat? You have not made any specific threat, except stating you will do what the law allows you to do such as asking the visitor to leave.

Comment: Isn't that just the same as Florida's castle doctrine?

Comment: Aside: seen painted on a wall in UK is "Trespassers will be sho" and the wall runs out at that point. Presumably it was meant to continue as "will be shown the door".

Comment: Reads like a simple declaration of fact and intent per the law.  Like a store posting "shoplifters will be prosecuted".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S. it does not.  U.S. has strong Castle Law doctrines and self-defense laws that allow the use of firearms for self-defense within the home.   The sign is that the homeowner is armed and will defend himself if there is an intruder.   Florida is also a stand your ground state which means that in public, self-defense is valid use of force for civilians even if they have the ability to flee the would be criminal.

As anecdotal evidence, when I was living in the state, my boss was telling me the story of how he got a gun and went to do some paperwork at the sheriff's office.  When the deputy received the paperwork, he saw that the gun was going to be used for home defense and told my boss, "In the case of home defense, if, God forbid someone enters your home looking to do harm to you and yours, remember:  Shoot to kill.  It's less paperwork for us."